# jQuery 1.4.4 -- .val() doesn't return value but text from <Select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume we have the following dropdown list

```
<select id="status">
    <option value='123' selected="selected">OPEN</option>
    <option value='987'>CLOSE</option>
</select>
```

in jQuery 1.4.4, if call

```
j('#status').val();
```

it only returns "OPEN", but not '123'

How to solve this issue? Really want the value of that option instead of text.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: 1.4.4? Let me borrow your time machine please. `=]`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g7HTA/

Comment: jquery.js has a line of comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4.... This is the year of 2012 right? :)

Comment: 1.4.4 was released [2 years ago](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/), the current stable version is [1.8.2](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js) and I'm pretty sure it doesn't happen on the stable version (even though Hazmat just showed that it doesn't happen in 1.4.4 either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#status option:selected').val();`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
j('#status option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after digging for a while, I found the solution to this issue(should only apply to that specific version), this expression:

```
 $('input[name=status]').val()
```

should give the value instead of text of selected option.

So leave this answer for the record.

Cheers